# How to filter a groupby object such that a column value lies in a range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe grouped on a column `PID`. The dataframe contains another column `year`. I want to find out all those PID for whom there exist separate records where `year > 1990` and `year < 1970`.

I tried the following approach, but the result is not what I expect:

```
g = df.groupby('PID')
g.filter(lambda x: ( ((x['year'] < 1970) | (x['year'] > 1990)).all() )
```

But this includes PIDs which satisfy just one of the two conditions. I need PIDs for whom there are records for both year < 1970 and year > 1990.

Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

this dataframe is grouped on `PID` to produced the grouped object `g` written above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g = df.groupby('PID')
g.filter(lambda x: ((x['year'] < 1970).any() & (x['year'] > 1990).any()))
```

`x['year'] < 1970` will return a boolean series where each record in the group will be checked for this condition. We want at least one occurrence of `year < 1970`, which will be checked by `.any()`. Similarly for the condition `year > 1990`. Finally, we want both these conditions to be true, hence the `&` in between.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = df.loc[df["year"] < 1970, "PID"].drop_duplicates()
output = d1[d1.isin(df.loc[df["year"] > 1990, "PID"])]
```